# prove\disprove if $f\circ g$ is invertible then $g\circ f$ is invertible

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

The question is to prove\disprove that if $f\circ g$ is invertible then $g\circ f$ is invertible. $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to A$. (f,g are functions)

I tried to prove it but always got stuck, so I began wondering it's a disapproval.

To disprove I chose g as injective and non-surjective function, while f chosen to be surjective and non-injective.

Thus, I get $f\circ g$ as invertible, however $g\circ f$ isn't a function and thus can't be invertible (as a disproof).

Is it correct what I did here? would appreciate your notes.

Comment: Why do you say $g\circ f$ is not a function?

Comment: If $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$ are functions, then $g \circ f$ will always be a function. Whether or not is it invertible is another story.

Comment: So is it a proof??

Comment: No. If $g \circ f$ is a function, it *can* be invertible.

Comment: @Ami: It's best to construct a counterexample. (A "failure to prove" is inconclusive. :) Suggestion: Let $A$ be a set of two elements and $B$ be a set of one element. You don't have much choice for $f$ and $g$; what do you conclude in this case?

Comment: If, in addition, $f$ is one-one and $g$ is onto, the claim becomes true.

Comment: Of course it's always a function — you *can't* prove *that*. But it doesn't have to be invertible. $g$ might be a one-sided inverse of $f$. The same as non-square matrices.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: suppose $B=\{0\}$ and $A=\{1,2\}$. For any function $g\colon B\to A$ and any function $f\colon A\to B$, the function $f\circ g\colon B\to B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is false for a very general reason: it would imply that all surjections are bijections, as would also be all injections, which is known to be trivially false.

Indeed, if $f\colon A\to B$ is a surjection, there exists a map $g\colon B\to A$ such that $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_B$, which is a bijection. If the implication were true, $g\circ f$ would be a bijection, which implies $f$ is an injection. Hence $g$ would be a bijection.

A similar argument  shows all injections would be  surjections, hence bijections.

As a consequence, all natural numbers would be equal.

Comment: and that would be a serious contradiction. thus - the assume was wrong - then gf isn't invertible?

Comment: I didn't say that: $g\circ f$ *need not*  be invertible – but it may. If $f$ is bijective, it is true.